# make a VBS file click a button

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a `VBS` file that when you open it launches a tab in Google Chrome then clicks a button. In this case [PLAY].

*Here is my script:*

```
Dim iURL 
Dim objShell

iURL = "http://www.roblox.com/games/292439477/NEW-GUNS-Phantom-Forces-Beta"

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
WScript.Sleep(3000)
Document.getElementById("MultiplayerVisitButton").Click()
```

This however does not work if anyone has a way to make it actually click it that would be nice.

Comment: Amount of scripts and methods tried: 24 Amount that have worked: 0

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear as if you have passed the Chrome Document into your Document object.

Try adding two references: Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library, then:

```
Dim iURL
Dim objShell
Dim Document As HTMLDocument
Dim Elem As IHTMLElement
Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection

iURL = "http://www.roblox.com/games/292439477/NEW-GUNS-Phantom-Forces-Beta"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
WScript.Sleep (3000)
Document = objShell.HTMLDocument
Elements = Document.getelementsbyClassName("rbx-btn-primary-lg")
For Each Elem In Elements
    If Elem.innerText = "Play" Then
        Elem.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I'm VERY VERY new to VBScript and am i supposed to change line 3, 4, and 5 to something? if so please help me out here, also what do you mean by"


accept
It doesn't appear as if you have passed the Chrome Document into your Document object.

Try adding two references: Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library"

Comment: You may want to use "Selenium Wrapper" to effectively automate Chrome.
[link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/)

Comment: From the menu, click "Tools", select "References", find "Microsoft Internet Controls", and click the checkbox. Find "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and click the checkbox. Click "OK". You now will have those two reference libraries imported into your project.

Comment: You can ignore posting an answer, I gave up, I'm not going to be making this.